# Rails - hidden_field in a partial form - erroring or not rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, hidden-field, partials

chap_comment_controller.rb contains

```
def create
    @chap_comment = current_user.chap_comments.build(chap_comment_params)
    if @chap_comment.save
      flash[:success] = "Comment created!"
    else
      render fallovercoswrong
    end
  end
```

I have a partial - _chap_comment_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@chap_comment) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :comment_text, placeholder: "Comment..." %> </div>
  <%= f.hidden_field :chapter_id, @chapter.id %>
  <%= @chapter.id %>is chapter id
  <%= f.submit "Post" %>
<% end %>
```

:chap_comment belongs_to :user and :chapter

The hidden field is causing problems. The code above returns the error

```
undefined method `merge' for 1:Fixnum
```

Changing the line to

```
<%= f.hidden_field_tag .....
```

returns

```
undefined method `hidden_field_tag' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007fa33165f7a8>
```

and

```
<%= hidden_field_tag ......
```

silently fails to put the hidden field into the rendered html. What's the best approach to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :chapter_id, @chapter.id %>
```

With:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :chapter_id, value: @chapter.id %>
```

`hidden_field` expects a hash as a second argument